# Laravel returns "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string"

Tags: php, laravel

I try upload an image through Laravel form but got this error message

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string
```

My code

```
//photo.blade.php
{{ Form::file('photo', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

//controller.php
$image      = Input::get('photo');
            $fileName   = $user->id . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
            $img->resize(500, 500, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();                 
            });

            $img->stream();
            Storage::disk('local')->put('images/'.$fileName, $img, 'public');
```

Comment: It seems `$image` is a string. What makes you think it would be an object with `getClientOriginalExtension()` method?

Comment: i already changed it into Input::file('photo'). but still error

Answer (score 2):

not sure which version of laravel is you working on. but try reading the file like this.

```
$image = Input::file('photo');
```

or from the request object.

```
request()->file('photo');
```

also like @Forkule said, make sure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

Comment: the error means the file was not uploaded, can you check the `input` name? ,

Comment: i got another error message, Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Answer (score 0):

use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

Like this one `<form method="post" action="giveaction" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$file = Input::file('photo');
```

or

```
$file = $request->file('photo');
```

Because

```
Input::get('photo');
```

returns a name of the file not the object of file.

Comment: i got another error message, Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Comment: can you print your request and check what is gets?